# Getting TF205022: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters in Xcode and TFS

Tags: xcode, tfs, tfvc

As suggested by https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-xcode I am putting my existing code to TFVC using git-tf. But my paths are deep. During check-in I am getting,

```
git-tf: TF205022: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters: 
/Users/VeryLongPath
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the path length limitation is really annoying, the most effective and  easy way still is spending some time **tweaking your *file/folder structure*** to make this work.

***For example:*** instead of `\xx\Build\Drop\ProjectName`, just use `\xx\Build\Drop` (or `\xx\Builds`) since the project name is also in the build name.

For the long path issue in TFS, there had been a related uservoice and now completed. However, it's still a problem in some areas.

> [Fix 260 character file name length limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4954037-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation)
>
> We’ve removed the limitation from the BCL for the basic file
>   manipulation functionality (CRUD). You can find more details here:
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/
>
> *Immo Landwerth Program Manager .NET*

Also suggest you to take a look at this great blog-[TFS Path Too Long problems](https://alistairbmackay.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/tfs-path-too-long-problems/) for how to deal with the issue.

In short currently its the TFVC limitation, from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/naming-restrictions#version-control-paths

```
Must not contain more than 259 Unicode characters for a single folder or file name.
```