# TFS merge Error with directory that no longer exists anywhere

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

I have inherited a project using Visual Studio Source Control. When the previous developers generated their css they did so in a convoluted folder structure including folders named with Guids, as such merely downloading the project was problematic because of Windows character limit.

The first thing I did was change this and remove the directory and all its contents from source control, I then created a branch in which to develop the application.

The problem occurs when trying to merge the branch back into the main project.

I get a Source Control merge wizard error (TF14078) stating that the path for the directories (that are long gone) is too long and exceeds the windows limits.

I have been manually merging from the branch but it would be more convenient to have the merges done the proper way.

Has anyone else ever encountered this and how did they fix it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Visual Studio Source Control". Do you mean TFVC?

Comment: Yes of course I mean that. I'm used to GIT

Answer (score 1):

In TFVC rename a folder/file name actually equals delete+ new.

Which means delete the old folder/file and create a new folder/file.

For your error info TF14078, this is a limit of Windows file system, and has been the limit for 10+ years. To work around the solution you will need to

- reduce the length of the server file path
- **map the long folder to a shorten local file path.** You can do that by
  editing your workspace mappings.

Also take a look at answer in this similar issue [Getting TF205022: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters in Xcode and TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885821/getting-tf205022-the-following-path-contains-more-than-the-allowed-259-characte/42897185#42897185)

If it's still not work, since you have mentioned `you created a branch in which to develop the application.` Not sure how you created the branch, if you not created the branch based on the main branch.

You may have to manually merge the branch.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I will try your solution.
The long path thing is something that I have already removed and am frustrated that somewhere TFVC isn't acknowledging that it's gone! Deleted!

Answer (score 0):

So, I was still unable to fix this for the branch I was using.
The only resolution I managed to find was to remove that branch and create a completely new one with a different name. So far I haven't encountered this issue again.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing Andrew, you could mark it as a reply